# Angular 2 ng-bootstrap styles are botched

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I had this working before, and then I upgraded a bunch of packages and rearranged some css, and now all of my ng-bootstrap component styles are ruined.

Please see this picture for a demonstration of the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjAEE.png

As you can see, the NgModal is being added to the DOM but it is essentially invisible unless unless I manually add "opacity: 1" to my `<ngb-modal-window></ngb-modal-window>` . Also the background/backdrop isn't darkened like it should be. Also the modal isn't vertically centered - half of it is floating off the top of the screen. Lastly, the datepicker styles are trashed also. I don't know what went wrong with the css styles, but I removed all possible global styles and this still occurs, so I'm at a loss for words. Any ideas on what styles might be causing this?

This is using Angular@2.4.2, ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.20, and bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, I guess bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.5 is no longer supported.